# Golang fatal error: concurrent map read and map write

Tags: dictionary, go

I'm writing minecraft server in Go, when server is being stressed by 2000+ connections I get this crash:

> fatal error: concurrent map read and map write/root/work/src/github.com/user/imoobler/limbo.go:78 +0x351
> created by main.main /root/work/src/github.com/user/imoobler/limbo.go:33 +0x368

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "bufio"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    connCounter = 0
)

func main() {
    InitConfig()
    InitPackets()

    port := int(config["port"].(float64))
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Server launched on port", port)
    go KeepAlive()
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        } else {
            connCounter+=1
            go HandleConnection(conn, connCounter)
        }
    }
}

func KeepAlive() {
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(15768735131534))
    keepalive := &PacketPlayKeepAlive{
        id: 0,
    }
    for {
        for _, player := range players {
            if player.state == PLAY {
                id := int(r.Uint32())
                keepalive.id = id
                player.keepalive = id
                player.WritePacket(keepalive)
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(20000000000)
    }
}

func HandleConnection(conn net.Conn, id int) {
    log.Printf("%s connected.", conn.RemoteAddr().String())

    player := &Player {
        id: id,
        conn: conn,
        state: HANDSHAKING,
        protocol: V1_10,
        io: &ConnReadWrite{
            rdr: bufio.NewReader(conn),
            wtr: bufio.NewWriter(conn),
        },
        inaddr: InAddr{
            "",
            0,
        },
        name: "",
        uuid: "d979912c-bb24-4f23-a6ac-c32985a1e5d3",
        keepalive: 0,
    }

    for {
        packet, err := player.ReadPacket()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }

        CallEvent("packetReceived", packet)
    }

    player.unregister()
    conn.Close()
    log.Printf("%s disconnected.", conn.RemoteAddr().String())
}
```

For now server is only "limbo".

Answer (score 100):

Generally speaking (without having access to the code where the error occurs) you have a few options. Here are two of them:

#### sync.RWMutex

Control access to the map with `sync.RWMutex{}`. Use this option if you have single reads and writes, not loops over the map. See [RWMutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex)

Here a sample with access control to `someMap` via `someMapMutex`:

```
var (
    someMap      = map[string]string{}
    someMapMutex = sync.RWMutex{}
)

go func() {
    someMapMutex.Lock()
    someMap["key"] = "value"
    someMapMutex.Unlock()
}()

someMapMutex.RLock()
v, ok := someMap["key"]
someMapMutex.RUnlock()
if !ok {
    fmt.Println("key missing")
    return
}
fmt.Println(v)
```

#### syncmap.Map

Use a `syncmap.Map{}` instead of a normal `map`. This map is already taking care of race issues but may be slower depending on your usage. `syncmap.Map{}`s main advantage lies with for loops. See [syncmap](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/syncmap)

```
var (
    someMap = syncmap.Map{}
)

go func() {
    someMap.Store("key", "value")
}()

v, ok := someMap.Load("key")
if !ok {
    fmt.Println("key missing")
    return
}
fmt.Println(v)

// with syncmap, looping over all keys is simple without locking the whole map for the entire loop
someMap.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {
    // cast value to correct format
    val, ok := value.(string)
    if !ok {
        // this will break iteration
        return false
    }
    // do something with key/value
    fmt.Println(key, val)

    // this will continue iterating
    return true
})
```

#### General Advice

You should test your server with `-race` option and then eliminate all the race conditions it throws. That way you can easier eliminate such errors before they occur.

```
go run -race server.go
```

See [golang race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector)

Comment: https://github.com/TyphoonMC/TyphoonLimbo there is full code that i use

Comment: Okay, sorry fror my mistake, its not probably map fault. 
        /root/work/src/github.com/user/imoobler/utils.go:33 i have posted my source code above.

Comment: Can you run `-race` detection?

Comment: Sure, https://pastebin.com/4sX56En3 full error after using -race argument

Comment: It seems to me like the line numers have changed to the code that is on https://github.com/TyphoonMC/TyphoonLimbo. `limbo.go:44` seems to be correct and points to this code `for _, player := range players {`. I assume the `players` map is accessed by multiple go routines. You need to control access to this `map` (via `Mutex`/`RWMutex`) or use a `syncmap` as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Yea, i removed some log lines. I will try first syncmap :)

Comment: I will add a sample for syncmap as well

Comment: players syncmap[int]*Player = make(syncmap[int]*Player) something like that? Im begginer in golang :)

Comment: see my Sample above. `syncmap` is a struct and works differently than a `map`. It has functions to `Load`, `Store`, `Range` over the content

Comment: undefined: syncmap in syncmap.Map

Comment: go get it first with `go get golang.org/x/sync/syncmap` and import with `import "golang.org/x/sync/syncmap"`

Comment: Okay i think i have replaced all with syncMap, now i get this: limbo.go:55: syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline, expecting comma or )
), current limbo.go: https://pastebin.com/QH92Khr6

Comment: you are not closing `players.Range(`. See my code above. Also have a look at `Gogland`. In my opinion it is currently the best IDE for go and free as it is still in development.

Comment: Okay, sorry for my "stupid" questions, i think i got last possible error in this case :P limbo.go:45: undefined: player
https://pastebin.com/MZA1VrFq

Comment: Have a look [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15). The first variable is the player, the second is of type `bool` telling you if the type cast was successful or not: `player, ok := value.(player)`. If you are sure all values will be of type `player` anyway, you can shorten it to `player := value.(player)`. Note: wasn't the `player` struct exported? Shouldn't it be `value.(Player)`? It is supposed to be a type!

Comment: players.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool { why this doesnt return any value? :o

Comment: it is not supposed to (see [documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/syncmap#Map.Range)). Note: the function given to the `Range` function returns a `bool`. This `bool` is used by the `Range` function to know if it should continue or not (`false` = stop, `true` = continue). The `Range` function itself does not have a return value.

Comment: So how can i use function x for every y value from list?

Comment: Https://pastebin.com/gutu2tUA I'm doing same things like in your sample, i want to manipulate player object (which represents value from map)

Comment: Here a working example: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nXLB-30xI3). Note: you cannot run it on playground. The syncmap package is not installed there. In your code: 1) don't `return false` if `ok` is not true. That was to show how to break the loop. You want to go through all items. 2) Save the changed player back to the map (see playground)