# Converting Standard Golang Map into a Sync.Map to Avoid Race Condition

Tags: go, thread-safety, mutex, race-condition, goroutine

I have the following line of code:

```
var a_map = make(map[string] []int)
```

Part of my code, which is utilizing the a_map variable occasionally throws the following error:

```
fatal error: concurrent map read and map write
```

In an attempt to create a more robust solution, one that is free from such an error, I would like to use a sync.Map as opposed to a generic map. I was inspired to do so by the only answer provided to this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585589/golang-fatal-error-concurrent-map-read-and-map-write). However, I am unclear as to the proper syntax for doing so.

For my first attempt I utilized the following line of code:

```
var a_map = make(sync.Map[string] []int)
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
...syntax error: unexpected ], expecting expression
```

Then I tried:

```
 sync_map := new(sync.Map)
 var a_map = make(sync_map[string] []int)
```

Which resulted in the same error:

```
...syntax error: unexpected ], expecting expression
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`sync.Map`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync?tab=doc#Map) is not a Go `map`, and so you cannot using the `a_map["key"]` syntax with it. Rather, it is a `struct` with methods providing the usual map operations. The syntax for using it is:

```golang
var m sync.Map
m.Store("example", []int{1, 2, 3})
fmt.Println(m.Load("example")) // [1 2 3] true
```

-- https://play.golang.org/p/7rbEG_x0mrC

Depending on the source of your concurrency, you may require similar synchronisation of the []int values under each key, which sync.Map will not give you. sync.Map only provides load/store synchronisation per key. Drop a comment if so, and we can try to help you out further.

Comment: Here is a link to a question on the syntax issue I'm currently facing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299470/working-with-slices-and-golang-sync-map-structure

Comment: If my post solves your syntax problems, then please accept the answer and I will look at your next question.