# Working with Slices and Golang sync.Map Structure

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, race-condition, goroutine

In order to debug some concurrency issues, I am in the process of switching part of my code from working on a regular Golang map to working on a sync.Map. However, when I try to run my new code, I am encountering two errors that I'm not sure how to debug.

The original code block:

```
        sync_mutex.Lock()
        if _, ok := the_map[cur_h]; ok {

            the_map[cur_h] = append(the_map[cur_h], cur_id)

        } else {

            value := []int{cur_id}
            the_map[cur_h] = value

        }
        sync_mutex.Unlock()
```

The new code block:

```
if _, ok := sync_map.Load(cur_h); ok {
                sync_mutex.Lock()
                cur_slice, _ := sync_map.Load(cur_h)
                updtd_slice := append(cur_slice, cur_id) // error #1

                sync_map.Store(cur_h, updtd_slice)
                map_mutex.Unlock()

            } else {
                map_mutex.Lock()
                value := []int{cur_id}
                sync_map.Store(cur_h, []int{value}) // error #2
                sync_mutex.Unlock()

            }
```

The error that is being thrown is:

```
... first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}
... cannot use value (type []int) as type int in array or slice literal
```

Comment: Note the caveats in Burak Serdar's answer, and this paragraph from the `sync.Map` description: *The Map type is optimized for two common use cases: (1) when the entry for a given key is only ever written once but read many times, as in caches that only grow, or (2) when multiple goroutines read, write, and overwrite entries for disjoint sets of keys. In these two cases, use of a Map may significantly reduce lock contention compared to a Go map paired with a separate Mutex or RWMutex.*

Answer (score 0):

`sync_map.Load` returns an `interface{}`, that's the reason why you got that first error. You have to use type assertions to get the underlying type:

```
cur_slice_i, _ := sync_map.Load(cur_h)
cur_slice := cur_slice_i.([]int)
updtd_slice := append(cur_slice, cur_id)
```

Not that above, cur_slice_i can be nil. Even though you first check and load, if somebody removes that key from the map in another goroutine, you may get nil here.

The second error is again a type mismatch: value is an int array already, so:

```
sync_map.Store(cur_h, value)
```

Your first use of map with a mutex is correct. If you use the same pattern in all the other goroutines that access that map, then you shouldn't run into problems related to concurrent access to map.

Comment: While this would avoid the errors, there is a risk of losing cur_id values between simultaneous Load and Store calls. And might the slice append also need a mutex around it?

Comment: Using mutex (without sync.Map), you wouldn't need a mutex around slice updates if all map access used that mutex, *and* no slices were updated outside the critical block. How would cur_id values be lost?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised your solution was to be used within a Mutex. If it is, why bother with sync.Map at all?