# How to kill command Exec in difference Function in Golang

Tags: go, ffmpeg, webrtc

i'm making screen record web based using command exec to run FFMPEG. here I created a startRecording function but I am still confused about stopping the command process in the stopRecording function, because the command is executed in the startRecording function. How to stop a process that is already running in the srartRecording function in the stopRecording function?

here my code

```golang
//Handler to create room/start record
func RoomCreate(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    fileName := "out.mp4"
    fmt.Println(fileName)
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        fileName = os.Args[1]
    }

    

    errCh := make(chan error, 2)
    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    // Call to function startRecording
    go func() { errCh <- startRecording(ctx, fileName) }()

    go func() {
        errCh <- nil
    }()
    err := <-errCh
    cancelFn()
    if err != nil && err != context.Canceled {
        log.Fatalf("Execution failed: %v", err)
    }
    
    return c.Redirect(fmt.Sprintf("/room/%s", guuid.New().String()))
}



//Function to run command FFMPEG
func startRecording(ctx context.Context, fileName string) error {
    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancelFn()
    // Build ffmpeg
    ffmpeg := exec.Command("ffmpeg",
        "-f", "gdigrab",
        "-framerate", "30",
        "-i", "desktop",
        "-f", "mp4",
        fileName,
    )
    // Stdin for sending data
    stdin, err := ffmpeg.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    //var buf bytes.Buffer
    defer stdin.Close()
    // Run it in the background
    errCh := make(chan error, 1)

    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("Executing: %v\n", strings.Join(ffmpeg.Args, " "))
        
        if err := ffmpeg.Run(); err != nil {
            return
        }
        //fmt.Printf("FFMPEG output:\n%v\n", string(out))
        errCh <- err
    }()
    // Just start sending a bunch of frames
    for {
        
        // Check if we're done, otherwise go again
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return ctx.Err()
        case err := <-errCh:
            return err
        default:
        }
    }
}

//Here function to stop Recording
func stopRecording(ctx context.Context) error {
//Code stop recording in here
}
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminating a Process Started with os/exec in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886531/terminating-a-process-started-with-os-exec-in-golang)

Comment: BTW you can remove the `default` statement from `select`, It will wait for either context to be done or reading from errCH. This way you don't need to use `for {}`

Comment: @medasx in the answer to the question exemplifies the kill process in one function. well what i mean is different function

Comment: Yeah well you have to store that cmd somewhere or at least the cancelFunc, simple map with RWmutex is enough.

Comment: @medasx Hello, can you please give me a solution in the answer column? I still can't understand RWMutex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested from comments.

The basic idea is to use **global** storage to store your active commands. It doesn't necessarily be global but you need to have bigger scope so that your functions can access it.

```golang
var commands = map[string]*exec.Cmd{}

func startRecording(fileName string) error {
    ffmpeg := exec.Command("ffmpeg",
        "-f", "gdigrab",
        "-framerate", "30",
        "-i", "desktop",
        "-f", "mp4",
        fileName,
    )
    commands[fileName] = ffmpeg
    ...
}

func stopRecording(fileName string) error {
    cmd, ok := commands[fileName]
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("command not found")
    }
    defer func() {
        delete(commands, fileName)
    }()
    return cmd.Process.Kill()
}
```

You probably want to use  [sync.Mutex](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex) or [sync.RWMutex](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex) to avoid [concurrent map writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585589/golang-fatal-error-concurrent-map-read-and-map-write).

So your `commands` cloud look like:

```golang
type Commands struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    items map[string]*exec.Cmd
}
// use Commands.Lock() for writing, Commands.RLock() for reading
```