# How to solve golang fatal error: concurrent map write

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency, google-cloud-pubsub, fatal-error

I am using google pubsub to publish a lot of records which is happening concurrently, but after few dozens of publishes, I get an error : concurrent map write.

I have read that I am suppose to use sync.Map{} or sync.Mutex, but I haven't found an example that helped me understand how to use it in my specific situation.

Here is a code snippet that causes me problems:

```
md := metadata.Collect(ctx)
    records, err := s.emailRepository.SetCurrentVersionWithEnsure(ctx, md.GetTransactionId(), valid)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, value := range records {
        go s.pub.PublishAction(md, value)
    }

    return nil
```

Variable records is of type map[string][]byte

If anyone can help with this, I would be grateful. Cheers !

Comment: Hope this will help [Exploring the Golang Builtin — Sync](https://medium.com/@pcpratheesh/exploring-the-golang-builtin-sync-54475320d4d4)

Comment: "How to solve golang fatal error: concurrent map write" don't write concurently to a map. "I have read that I am suppose to use sync.Map{} or sync.Mutex, but I haven't found an example that helped me understand how to use it in my specific situation." Your situation is not specific. You'll have to learn how to synchronise access.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple goroutines are trying to read and write on your map concurrently or simultaneously. Yes, `sync.Mutex` is one of the workarounds that can fix that error because it ensures that only one goroutine can access the map. Aside from sync.Mutex, you can also use `sync.RWMutex`. For accessing the map concurrently, you can use `sync.Map`. You can refer to this [SO case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585589/golang-fatal-error-concurrent-map-read-and-map-write).

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki since this is the possible known workaround and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem for my particular case.

In method PublishAction there is a line of code that checks if pubsub topic exists. This line does that by pinging google server, but there is a limit of how many times you can hit that server in a minute.